# How To Take The Value From A JTextField And Move It Into A Int Variable

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, parseint

I have been trying to create a JFrame program that takes two numbers and an 
operation(inside jcombobox) to calculate the answer. I need to take the user input for number 1 and 2 and assign the value to an int that can be used in the calculation of the answer. num1 is the int variable and num1field is the name of the textfield.

```
    num1field.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(num1field.getText());
                num1field.setText(num1);
            }
        }
     );
```

And yes the num1 int has already been declared at the top of the class. I am getting an error where it says setText.

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Answer as per MadProgrammer (1+), but in the future, if you're getting an error, it's a good idea to post the error here for us to see. It usually tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: your code has no sense at all.. 1) `setText()` expects a String. 2) you are parsing a String to an Integer and setting the same value to the same textfield

Answer (score 2):

There is no method `JTextField#setText(int)`, you can only supply a `String`

```
num1field.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
```

Should work

You may like to take a look at [How to use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and [How to use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) which may provide you with better functionality for what you are trying to achieve

**Updated with example of idea how to calculate resulting value**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class QuickCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new QuickCalc();
    }

    public QuickCalc() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField numField1;
        private JTextField numField2;
        private JComboBox cbModifier;
        private JLabel lblResult;

        private JButton equals;

        public TestPane() {

            numField1 = new JTextField(4);
            numField2 = new JTextField(4);
            cbModifier = new JComboBox();
            equals = new JButton("=");
            lblResult = new JLabel("?");

            DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
            model.addElement("+");
            model.addElement("-");
            model.addElement("/");
            model.addElement("x");
            cbModifier.setModel(model);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(numField1);
            add(cbModifier);
            add(numField2);
            add(equals);
            add(lblResult);

            equals.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numField1.getText());
                        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(numField2.getText());

                        // Make your calculations here...
                        // Update the lblResult with the resulting value...
                        lblResult.setText(String.valueOf(42));                        
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        nfe.printStackTrace();
                        lblResult.setText("Bad numbers");
                    }
                }                    
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is still telling me that the answer is zero no matter what I do. If you need me to I can post the whole program.

Comment: Is your `actionPerformed` method begin called?

Comment: I would also recommend that you extract the values from the text fields only when you need them...

Comment: I do not have to call my actionperformed because it is being put inside the parameters of num1field.addActionListener

Comment: No, but it will only be called if the user presses [enter], otherwise you `num1` field will never be changed...

Comment: Ok so where do I need to call the action performed

Comment: You don't. This done automatically. What I suggest is, when the user presses the "calculate" button, you grab all the values at that time. There's no gurentee that the ActionListeners of the text fields will be called

Comment: but num1 and num2 aren't getting values because I don't know how to give them the value of the text box

Comment: But your example code showed that you can convert the String value from the text field to int...

Comment: could it be a problem with my calculate button? And by the way Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: I've added an example of what I'm talking about.  Basically, my example doesn't care about the values in the text field UNTIL you try and make the calculation...in this case, press the "=" button...

Comment: Alright thanks for helping me:) I really appreciate it! This was hard since I am just being introduced to Gui development. Is there a way that I can repay you? How do I select your answer as the answer?